# list[idx] = strdup(tok[1] +tok[2]) or initial malloc to size of list -C

Tags: c, debugging, malloc, strcat, strdup

I have a code that has an invalid write in valgrind. What I tried to do was strcat the idx I malloc'd. I would like to know what size to strdup() so I can put spaces in between the number of tokens, which are the in the char *argv[].

Here is a small piece of the code

If you are interested in a larger picture of how the tokens are collected form getline you can see the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27394313/getline-loop-for-stdin-has-segmentatoin-fault-after-each-loop-c

```
// parent will wait for child to exit
id = wait( &status );

if( id < 0 ) {
    perror( "wait" );

} else {

    int idx = 0;
    histL[count-1] =  strdup(argv[idx]);
    //printf("Token added %s size of %i is\n", argv[idx], i);
    for (idx = 1; idx < i-1; idx++) {       //-1 because no need last one
        strcat( histL[count-1], " ");
        strcat( histL[count-1], argv[idx]);
        //printf("Token added %s\n", argv[idx]);
    }
    //printf("Exit for Loop\n");
//puts( "Parent is now exiting." );

//exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
    }
```

**Here** is the best that I can do at this point

```
int idx = 0;
histL[count-1] =  ( char* )malloc( sizeof( argv ) + (i*sizeof(" ")));// histLSize );    //strdup(argv[idx]);
strcpy(histL[count-1], strdup(argv[idx]));
//printf("Token added %s size of %i is\n", argv[idx], i);
for (idx = 1; idx < i-1; idx++) {       //-1 because no need last one
    histL[count-1] = strcat( histL[count-1], " ");
    histL[count-1] = strcat( histL[count-1], argv[idx]);
    //printf("Token added %s\n", argv[idx]);
}
```

**Fixed it**

```
int idx = 0;
histL[count-1] =  ( char* )malloc( sizeof( &argv ) + (i*sizeof(" ")));// histLSize );   //strdup(argv[idx]);
strcpy(histL[count-1], argv[idx]);
//printf("Token added %s size of %i is\n", argv[idx], i);
for (idx = 1; idx < i-1; idx++) {       //-1 because no need last one
    histL[count-1] = strcat( histL[count-1], " ");
    histL[count-1] = strcat( histL[count-1], argv[idx]);
    //printf("Token added %s\n", argv[idx]);
}
```

Comment: A string returned from `strdup` will have *NO* room for concatenation. The memory allocation is sized specifically to the string length of the string passed + 1 for the terminator. I.e. both of your `strcat` invokes are *guaranteed* to invoke *undefined behavior*. (ok, the second one *may* not, but only if it is a zero-length string, which would be pointless; the damage is already done from the first one regardless).

Comment: Alright Whoz Craig, you are right, the first error says invalid write of size `==18236== Invalid write of size 2
==18236==    at 0x401823: main (mysh.c:424)
==18236==  Address 0x51fd284 is 4 bytes inside a block of size 5 alloc'd
==18236==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64` I would try the strcats like `histL[count-1] = strdup(strcat( histL[count-1], " "));`

Comment: That still don't do it. You need a buffer large enough to hold the length of *all* strings plus a terminator. Burying `strcat( histL[count-1], " ")` inside a `strdup` isn't going to change the undefined behavior being invoked.

Comment: I would definitely just say `histL[count-1] =  strdup(argv);` and throw the whole array but I need a space between each index. It might seem like I should find number of tokens first. histL[count-1] =  (char*)malloc(sizeof(argv)+ (sizeof(" "))*idx);` What do you think man? Thanks for the comments, I hope I am addressing your concern with my solution.

Comment: It is highly  likely that *still* won't do it,  That`malloc` is very likely incorrectly requesting the size of a pointer-to-pointer (a `char**`) plus 2 (`sizeof(" ")`), assuming `argv` is either `char* argv[]` or `char ** argv`, which are equivalent. If `argv` is `char argv[M][N]` a *true* array of arrays, it *may* work. C pointer code isn't something you just throw up and hope it sticks. You need to *know* what you're doing or catastrophe will be in the making.

Comment: hwo to fix code indentation when copying code that is already indented?

Answer (score 2):

You are not calculating the `malloc()` size correctly at all.  You need to use two loops, one to calculate the size, then another to copy the strings after allocating the memory:

```
int lastidx = i-1;

int size = strlen(argv[0]) + 1;
for (int idx = 1; idx < lastidx; ++idx) {
    size += (1 + strlen(argv[idx]));
}

histL[count-1] = (char*) malloc(size);

strcpy(histL[count-1], argv[0]);
for (int idx = 1; idx < lastidx; ++idx) {
    strcat(histL[count-1], " ");
    strcat(histL[count-1], argv[idx]);
}
```

Or better:

```
int lastidx = i-1;

int size = strlen(argv[0]) + 1;
for (int idx = 1; idx < lastidx; ++idx) {
    size += (1 + strlen(argv[idx]));
}

char *str = (char*) malloc(size);

int len = strlen(argv[0]);
memcpy(str, argv[0], len);
size = len;

for (int idx = 1; idx < lastidx; ++idx) {
    str[size++] = ' ';
    len = strlen(argv[idx]);
    memcpy(str+size, argv[idx], len);
    size += len;
}

str[size] = '\0';
histL[count-1] = str;
```

Comment: I don't mean to be critical in my comments. Whozcraig and you answer recieved 0 errors. Great job, I like how you included the " " which were needed

Comment: Apologies amok, Remy, I totally spaced the embedded space. glorious answer, and +1.